# Dynamically created join in ax 2012

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

Is this possible to create outer join between two tables after some event - for example when user will click a button?

Scenario: I must make form displaying all products. Difficulty is that some products have external numbers. When product have 2 external numbers and data sources are joined in grid are two almost identical records and our client is not satisfied. He wants default one record - maybe two if he use some button. I think the solution of this problem is make connection between tables from code after client use button so this is mu question - is this possible and eventually how to do it but I will be also grateful  for clues to solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to [en- or disable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/querybuilddatasource.enabled.aspx) the outer joined datasource with the external item numbers with the button. But I would recommend to find another solution (probably with a separate grid that displays the external item numbers for the selected item or with a FactBox if you are on a list page).

Comment: Also you could consider using exist join rather than inner join, this avoids "duplicates".

Comment: Solution with factbox was also rejected. If I use exist join I see only these records which have external number but not all records dont need to have it.

Comment: And if you use outer join you may see the same record several times. Consider using display field (maybe listing serveral external numbers comma separated). This will not be searchable of cause.

Comment: This combination is not solvable: 1) must only show one record even with two external numbers. 2) must be searchable in the grid.